# How do I change color using an ifelse() statement in an interaction network?

Tags: r

I am using the package bipartite to plot a plant-pollinator interaction. I convert my raw data to the data frame used by the package and plot the web. But I want the color of the interaction in the plot to be different for one species (B.griseocollis) and I cannot get this to work.

Below is my code:

```
frame2webs(bombus_rxc, varnames= c("ID","beesp","trtmnt"), type.out="list",
 emptylist=TRUE)

f2w <- frame2webs(bombus_rxc, varnames= c("ID","beesp","trtmnt"), 
type.out="list", emptylist=TRUE)
```

FYI "pbg" is one of the "trtmnts" I have

```
plotweb(f2w$pbg)

plotweb(f2w$pbg, col.interaction = ifelse(as.character(bombus_rxc$beesp) == 
"B.griseocollis", "cyan4", "grey80"))
```

Two of the interactions turn to cyan but not the correct two. I realize no one has my data set but just curious if there is something obviously wrong with my argument in the col.interaction statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling your colors, you're calling a vector that doesn't line up with your final plot.

Here's a rough reproducible example (you should try to make these for your data to make answering your questions easier):

```
bombus_rxc=mtcars
bombus_rxc$ID=rownames(bombus_rxc)
bombus_rxc$beesp=bombus_rxc$carb
bombus_rxc$trtmnt=rep(c("pbg","abc"))
bombus_rxc
```

And here is how you can make the plot work:

```
frame2webs(bombus_rxc, varnames= c("ID","beesp","trtmnt"), type.out="list",
 emptylist=TRUE)

f2w <- frame2webs(bombus_rxc, varnames= c("ID","beesp","trtmnt"), 
type.out="list", emptylist=TRUE)

plotweb(f2w$pbg)

plotweb(f2w$pbg,col.interaction=ifelse(colnames(f2w$pbg)==1,"cyan4","grey80"))
```

Hope it works for your real data!

Comment: Glad to hear! Please [accept the above answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in that case.

Comment: Thanks @desc for your useful example. This seems to work for coloring interactions in one direction only - from higher trophic level (e.g. pollinators) to lower trophic level (e.g. plants). If you also have some code to color by plants, that would be great. Unfortunately. the help of `plotweb` function does't cover well the coloring aspect.

Comment: Hi @Valentin, You could try changing the `ifelse` to look for `rownames` like this: `plotweb(f2w$pbg,col.interaction=ifelse(rownames(f2w$pbg)=="Merc 230","cyan4","grey80"))`.

Comment: Hi @desc, That was also my first guess, which works with your test data, but if I try more complex interactions will not do the expected, e.g. try: `data(Safariland); plotweb(Safariland,col.interaction=ifelse(rownames(Safariland)=="Aristotelia chilensis" ,"cyan4","grey80"))`. It even colors other interactions where the selected lower trophic species has nothing to do with. I think the row index is not that straightforward related to the interaction index as the column index is. Any thoughts?

Comment: One "unorthodox" way to temporarily solve this was to simply invert lower with upper trophic levels, since the `colnames` approach seems to work without issues.